# xpath for parents sibling

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

My Html looks like this

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <span>
            <img>fieldId:
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>
            <input value="false" type="text">
            <input type="hidden" >
        </span>
    </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

I want to find the text input field but i know only **fieldId** which is  present under 1st td/span/img 
I wrote xpath like this

```
//span[contains(text(),'fieldId')]/../following-sibling::td
```

But it finds all the td which is present after 1st td so i tried like this

```
//span[contains(text(),'fieldId')]/../following-sibling::td[0]
```

But this is not working

Where am i going wrong ??

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath index starts from `1`, not `0` :

```
//span[contains(text(),'fieldId')]/../following-sibling::td[1]
```

Alternatively, you can try this way :

```
//td[contains(span, 'fieldId')]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Comment: Thanks index was the issue  @har07

Answer (score 0):

Try this
(//input[@type="text"])[1](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/real-browser-manual/building-a-testcase/how-locate-element-the-page/xpath-locator-examples/) this will select the first input field with type text from the page

Use the following link for more examples:

[Click for more details](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/real-browser-manual/building-a-testcase/how-locate-element-the-page/xpath-locator-examples/)

Also yes xpath index starts from 1 not 0.